# Java compiler error: "public type .. must be defined in its own file"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I am trying to compile this:

```
public class DNSLookUp {
    public static void main(String[] args)   {
        InetAddress hostAddress;
        try  {
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            System.out.println (hostAddress.getHostAddress());
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException uhe)  {
            System.err.println("Unknown host: " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

I used javac dns.java, but I am getting a mess of errors:

```
dns.java:1: error: The public type DNSLookUp must be defined in its own file
    public class DNSLookUp {
                 ^^^^^^^^^
dns.java:3: error: InetAddress cannot be resolved to a type
    InetAddress hostAddress;
    ^^^^^^^^^^^
dns.java:6: error: InetAddress cannot be resolved
    hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^
dns.java:9: error: UnknownHostException cannot be resolved to a type
    catch (UnknownHostException uhe)  {
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
4 problems (4 errors)
```

I have never compiled/done Java before. I only need this to test my other programs results. Any ideas? I am compiling on a Linux machine.

Comment: 4 is not a "mess" of errors. 400 may be, but not 4. And please try to keep the questions as self-contained as possible, we don't want to be chasing all over the internet, looking for your code, while trying to help you out :-)

Comment: Sorry! I still need to figure out how to format on SO, thanks for the edit!

Comment: For future reference, 4 spaces before a line will format it as such, and you can use backticks to do the same formatting inline. [This link](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) explains it pretty well.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The file needs to be called `DNSLookUp.java` and you need to put:

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;
```

At the top of the file

Comment: Thanks! That makes a lot more sense~

Comment: In case anyone else wonders, the file needs to be renamed because the filename needs to match the class name. If I'm stupid enough to miss that, and therefore miss the solution to my problem, maybe someone else is too.

Answer (score 6):

The answers given here are all good, but given the nature of these errors and in the spirit of 'teach a man to fish, etc, etc':

1. Install IDE of choice (Netbeans is an easy one to start with)
2. Setup your code as a new project
3. Click the lightbulb on the line where the error occurs
4. Select the fix you'd like
5. Marvel at the power of the tools you have available

Comment: IntelliJ has a community edition. http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/free_java_ide.html

Comment: @Jayan - Yeah, we're spoilt for choice when it comes to rich IDEs. I only have experience with Netbeans and Eclipse, and, while they're both fantastic, I think Netbeans would have a shallower learning curve for those new to the language.

Comment: +1 for Netbeans. I like IntelliJ but the commercial one. Many of significant things are not there in community edition.

Comment: I would imagine the OP will google "choose java IDE" as soon as they see this answer so debating it in the comments is probably irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

Rename the file as `DNSLookUp.java` and import appropriate classes.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class DNSLookUp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InetAddress hostAddress;
        try {
            hostAddress = InetAddress.getByName(args[0]);
            System.out.println(hostAddress.getHostAddress());
        } catch (UnknownHostException uhe) {
            System.err.println("Unknown host: " + args[0]);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the classes you're using. e.g.:

import java.net.*;

To import all classes from the java.net package.

You also can't have a public class DNSLookUp in a file named dns.java. Looks like it's time for a Java tutorial...

Answer (score 0):

Coming from ["The public type <<classname>> must be defined in its own file" error in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19814713/the-public-type-classname-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file-error-in-eclipse) which was marked as duplicate.

I'm thus answering this "duplicate" here:
On Eclipse, you can prepare all your `public class`es in one file, then `right-clic -> Refactor -> Move Type to New File`.
That's not exactly the right workaround (this won't let you have multiple `public class`es in one file at compile time), but that will let you move them around in their proper files when you'll be ready.

Coming from C#, that's an annoying enforced limitation for do-forgettable (tutorial) classes, nonetheless a good habit to have.