# java:4: error: The public type NumberAdder must be defined in its own file

Tags: java

java:4: error: The public type NumberAdder must be defined in its own file

```
import java.util.Scanner;


    public class NumberAdder{

        public static void main(String arg[]){
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.print("1st Number: ");
            int one = in.nextInt();

            System.out.print("2nd Number: ");
            int two = in.nextInt();

            int result = one + two;
            System.out.println("result = " + result);
        }
    }
```

my file name is `NumberAdder.java`.

How can this error be avoided?

Comment: Are you sure the name is exactly the same (no typos)? Did you put the class into a package you're not showing here?

Comment: Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084005/java-compiler-error-public-type-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file)

Comment: There is usually something that comes before the word `java` in that error. As in `abc.java:4` or `MyProject.java:4`. Don't you have anything there?

Answer (score 1):

If your file name and public class name differs then you get this type of error.

From the error The *public type* NumberAdder must be defined in its own file I am pretty sure that your file name is not NumberAdder.java