# InMemoryJavaCompiler cannot compile file

Tags: java

I'm trying to compile a .java file with InMemoryJavaCompiler
but i get an error.

My code:

```java
try {
    final var path = Paths.get("C:/EffectHandler.java");
            
    final var pathToStr = Files.readString(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    System.out.println(pathToStr);
            
    InMemoryJavaCompiler.newInstance().compile("EffectHandler", pathToStr);
} 
catch (final Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

My error:

```
[kind=ERROR, line=24, message=class main is public, should be declared in a file named main.java]
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.scripting.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compileAll(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:125)
    at com.l2jserver.gameserver.scripting.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compile(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:146)
    at com.l2jserver.TEST.main(TEST.java:44)
```

My file in C:

```
public class main
{   
    public static void main(final String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Compiled");
    }
}
```

The file is named EffectHandler.java

Comment: The error seems to be pretty clear - you need either to rename the file to `main.java` or to rename the class to `EffectHandler` to comply with the [basic rule: public type must be defined in its own file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084005/java-compiler-error-public-type-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Java compiler error: "public type .. must be defined in its own file"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084005/java-compiler-error-public-type-must-be-defined-in-its-own-file)

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as well as its solution, are explicitly written in the error message.
The class `main` needs to be in its own file - `main.java`.

Alternatively, if you don't want to change the filename, rename the class to `EffectHandler`

Comment: Now it give this: at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:719)
 at com.l2jserver.gameserver.scripting.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:27)